# Can new cabinets be installed with old floor tile cutouts?

Tags: kitchens, tile, cabinets

I'm doing a kitchen remodel. After ripping out the cabinets, I noticed that there were no tiles underneath them. Since the tiles are in good shape, is it possible use this exact same tile cutout with new cabinets? How likely is the new cabinet going to exactly fit these cutouts? Do the new cabinets even need to match exactly? Or is it much more preferable to install new floor tiles wall-to-wall?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you ordering custom cabinets? If so yes they can be mad to fit. If ordering premade cabinets. If the cabinet is larger the tile can be cut to allow the cabinet to fit. If the premade cabinets are smaller molding can be added to hide the gaps matching grout colors is almost impossible. Depending on the size of the kitchen the above choices may save a large amount of $.

Comment: I'm most likely going to order pre-made cabinets, since that will be cheaper than custom.

Comment: It looks like the tile went under the cabinets a bit, giving a little more grace on standardized cabinets working. The only thing will be a dishwasher or refrigerator placement, usually the floor is continuous under these appliances. Maybe not so much the dishwasher, but surely the refer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the replacements base cabinets cover the hole go for it. The cabinets will have a floor in them so you will be the only person who knows.